# Unexpected operator in if statement

Tags: shell, if-statement, operators, sh

In the following two lines I get this error?

What is wrong?

`Debian Buster`

> my.sh: 101: [: !=: unexpected operator
>
> my.sh: 103: [: !=: unexpected operator

```
if [ $CONTINUE != "y" ] && [ "$CONTINUE" != "n" ]; then

elif [ $CONTINUE = "n" ]; then
```

## update

```
echo "\nContinue downloading? [y/n]"
read CONTINUE

#   Error: Invalid argument
if [ $CONTINUE != "y" ] && [ $CONTINUE != "n" ]; then
    error "Invalid argument"
elif [ $CONTINUE = "n" ]; then
    echo "\nDonwload terminated!"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Are you actually using Bash or sh? This makes a crucial difference for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you’ve posted has various issues, which are highlighted by [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
Line 1:
echo "\nContinue downloading? [y/n]"
     ^-- SC2028: echo may not expand escape sequences. Use printf.

Line 2:
read CONTINUE
^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Line 5:
if [ $CONTINUE != "y" ] && [ $CONTINUE != "n" ]; then
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                             ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
if [ "$CONTINUE" != "y" ] && [ "$CONTINUE" != "n" ]; then

Line 7:
elif [ $CONTINUE = "n" ]; then
       ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
elif [ "$CONTINUE" = "n" ]; then

Line 8:
    echo "\nDonwload terminated!"
         ^-- SC2028: echo may not expand escape sequences. Use printf.
```

But despite these issues **the script actually otherwise *works as expected*** on Debian (Buster)’s default shell (which is `dash`). You might be running a non-default shell. The easiest way to solve your issue is therefore to

- Declare a valid [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)
- Fix the issues highlighted above.

Which leaves us with this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printf "\nContinue downloading? [y/n] "
read -r CONTINUE

error() {
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
    exit 1
}

if [ "$CONTINUE" != y ] && [ "$CONTINUE" != n ]; then
    error "Invalid argument"
elif [ "$CONTINUE" = n ]; then
    printf "\nDownload terminated!\n"
    exit
fi
```

(This also adds a definition for the undefined `error` call; substitute as appropriate.)